# How to alter label tag of fieldset in django admin page using admin.tabularinline

Tags: python, django, admin

I customized my add user form in my django admin, using admin.tabularinline. So whenever the admin adds a user, information about `User`model and `UserProfile` model is saved at the same time. However, the label tag of the UserProfile form says 'Staff Profiles'(with 's'). And it doesn't look good because there is only one profile for one user. Any ideas how to change the "Staff Profiles" into "Staff Profile"?
See the picture for reference:

[image]

Comment: Please check. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.verbose_name_plural), changing your `verbose_name_plural` in `UserProfileInline`

In admin declaration, add

```
class UserProfileInline(admin.YourInlineChoice):
    verbose_name_plural="Staff Profile"
    [Your params]
```